# Converting JSON dump strings into floats in Python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services

Trying to follow along with AWS's [DeepAR ML Tutorial](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/deepar_electricity/DeepAR-Electricity.ipynb)

Excuse my ignorance whenever it comes to JSON, but I understand it as it's preferable to pass strings rather than floats. I've tried to do this here and used UTF-8 as it must be a byte type.

```
def write_dicts_to_file(path, data):
with open(path, 'wb') as fp:
    for d in data:
        fp.write(json.dumps(d).encode("utf-8"))
        fp.write("\n".encode('utf-8'))
```

Passing these to the above function:

```
    %%time
write_dicts_to_file("train.json", training_data)
write_dicts_to_file("test.json", test_data)
```

My Targets are then written as strings, which is what I expect, but then I get later into AWS's code to here:

```
    %%time
data_channels = {

    "train": "{}/train/".format(data_location),
    "test": "{}/test/".format(data_location)
}

estimator.fit(inputs=data_channels, wait=True)
```

Which returns the error invalid float X, as my targets are still strings. How do pass just the targets in the JSON file as floats rather than the strings?

Comment: Why do you think it's preferable to pass strings instead of floats?  Floats (and every other representation of real numbers) has finite precision. This also goes for strings, of course. There's no way to precisely represent `1/3` in a decimal string, for example.

Comment: Unfamiliar with JSON best practices so that's what I read on other questions on this topic. Is there a way to write the JSON file while forcing the strings to floats?

Comment: JSON is text. So all types are converted to strings when you do json serializiation, and that can't be avoided. When I read your question, it's not clear to me what problem you are trying to solve here. There are cases when you might want to use some custom string representation of real numbers. The default implementation will provide you something like ~50 bits of precision. There's likely to be rounding errors, but for real world data, the rounding errors are typically insignificant.